# Не могу сделать Generic Nullable Enum

Tags: c#, null, enum

Есть класс (код немного абстрактный, но абсолютно рабочий):

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T: System.Enum
{
    public T? SomeProperty { get; } // ошибка
    //     ↑↑
}
```

Как видно, я хочу иметь *Nullable Enum*, тип которого передётся при создании экземляра класса.

Как я знаю, `Enum` сам по себе не может равняться `null`, почему тогда я не могу использовать `Nullable<T>` (`T?`)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719258/generic-nullable-enum

Comment: @Andrew я видел эту ссылку, вы хотите сказать что добиться такого невозможно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сколько я понимаю проблема твоего кода лежит в том, что [System.Enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=net-5.0) является **классом**, а использование нуллейбл типов требует от требя использования **структур**.

---

Сам энам возможно и не может иметь значение налл, но ты вполне можешь использовать конкретный энам как нуллейбл

```
public myEnum? instance = null;
```

если ты не переназначал тип, т.к. по дефолту это инт значения ( т.е. это структура)

---

В случае с генерик классом можно попробовать взять за основу код отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/50351847/4423545 и получить вот это:

```
//смотри наследование
public class SomeClass<T> where T: struct, System.Enum
{
    public T? SomeProperty { get; }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, я не думал, что порядок ограничения принципиален. Я до этого пробовал `where T: System.Enum, struct`